WPF проблема с подключения бд (ADO.NET)
Всем привет, столкнулся с такой проблемой, в рамках учебы проходим WPF в особенности взаимодействие с SQL Management Studio, начал делать приложение, сделал локальную БД, заимпортировал в нее данные и решил подключить к приложению, БД успешно подключается к приложению, но спустя 10-15 секунд все мои данные из БД начинают подсвечиваться ошибкой, решил попробовать подключить уже существующие БД, которые использовал в других приложениях, они подключается без каких-либо проблем и ошибок.
Пошагово описываю способ подключения, выбираю ADO.NET => Конструктор EF из базы данных => создать соединение => Ввожу имя локальной БД => Сертификацию указываю False => Выбираю нужную мне БД и таблицы => Происходит успешное подключение
Скрины с БД и ошибки: https://yapx.ru/album/XT7ed

У вас не ADO.NET, а EF, это две совершенно разные вещи, хоть и 2-я использует "под капотом" первую. Что касается ошибок - попробуйте просто пересобрать проект с очисткой (ПКМ - очистить, ПКМ - Пересобрать). Если не помогло, открываете папку с проектом, закрываете студию, удаляете из папки с проектом папки bin, obj, скрытую папку .vs, ну и файл .user - тем самым вы удалите весь "Кэш" и все временные файлы созданные студией. После пытайтесь открыть проект по новой и попробуйте его собрать. Если и это не помогает, то у вас нет NuGet пакетов. P.S. Советую EF писать руками, а не генератор.

Попробовал ваши 2 предложенных способа, результат к сожалению не изменился, единственное что могу подметить делал недавно еще 1 БД в Mysql, ради теста решил подключить ее таким же способом - ошибок нет, как перехожу к подключению нужной мне БД возникает данный казус

Management Studio - это GUI-интерфейс для работы с Sql Server. Между тем метка у вас стоит MySql, в комментарии вы тоже упомянули MySql. Уясните, что Sql Server и MySql - это две совершенно разные СУБД! Какую именно вы используете?

Ну что там, вы разобрались с тем, какую СУБД используете?
